Copy cells with text and font-color with openpyxl?
I try to copy some cells with colored fonts from one worksheet to antoher using openpyxl.
The cell A1 is only colored - and the cell A2 is richtext-colored (so only a part of the cell is colored)

Using the following code:
import openpyxl as ox
import os
import sys

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
fn = os.path.join(path, "test.xlsx")
wb = ox.load_workbook(fn, rich_text=True)
ws = wb["input"]
wsOut = wb["output"]

cell1 = ws["A1"]
cell1NEW = wsOut["A1"]
cell1NEW.value = cell1.value

cell1 = ws["A2"]
cell1NEW = wsOut["A2"]
cell1NEW.value = cell1.value

wb.save("test.xlsx")

But when i run the code only the cell A2 i copied correct.
For the cell A1 only the text is copied - without the coloring / the style.

How can i copy for both cells the coloring (the style)?

Excel stores font settings on two levels.
The cell style itself may have font settings. This then applies to the whole cell content.
And the cell may contain rich text which consists of text runs having font settings for each text run.
In your example the cell A1 has font settings of cell style which sets blue font color and special font size. The cell content itself is not rich text but the plain text "col" only.
The cell A2 has font settings of cell style which sets special font size only. And it contains rich text where the text run "TEXT" has special font color and font size. The font settings of cell style applies to the text "AAA" while the rich text text run only is "TEXT".
Cell.value gets or sets rich text content, if enabled.
Cell.font gets or sets font settings of cell style (of whole cell).
Thus you need setting the Cell.font too:
...
from copy import copy
...
cell1 = ws["A1"]
cell1NEW = wsOut["A1"]
cell1NEW.value = cell1.value
cell1NEW.font = copy(cell1.font)

cell1 = ws["A2"]
cell1NEW = wsOut["A2"]
cell1NEW.value = cell1.value
cell1NEW.font = copy(cell1.font)
...

To set Cell.font to be a copy of another cell's font, copy (of from copy import copy) needs to be used as there is not any special setter for Cell.font. The default setter will fail using simply = assignment.

thx for your reponse - 2 questions:

Why is this copy() necessary and why is not a simple assignment with = possible
The copy statement for for the cell A2 is not necessary cause its richtext - correct?
(beside that you have a small typo in your code - its cell1NEW and not cell NEW


@Rapid1898: 1): see my supplements; 2): It is necessary for the "AAA" text part, which is not rich text. Typo is corrected.
